# How to split String in xml?

Tags: xml, sapui5

I have one requirement, so need your help?

String coming from SAP Backend is - 85274|AC|Air|FS

Now I need to Split it in my xml view as shown below

GCN No - 85274
Bill - AC
Mode - Air
Payby - FS

Can anybody help me?

I tried like this

```html
<Label text="GCN No - {Xdata(1,5)}"/>
```

Comment: Order will be always same  GCN No - Bill - Mode  - Payby

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a formatter where you can simply write the javascript code to split and return the desired substring.

```html
Your xml code should look like this.
<Label text="{
    path:'odataPropertyPath',                 //The Odata path which returns "85274|AC|Air|FS" 
    formatter:'.formatLabel'
    }"
 />
```

And in your corresponding controller:

```js
formatLabel: function (oDataString) {

  // label = Split string here and get the desired Label
   
   return label;   
}
```

Here's a sample which explains how to use formatters in SAPUI5: [formatter example](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon20/2.05/en-US/0f/8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de/content.htm?no_cache=true)

Comment: Hello @Nandan Chaturvedi - whar does odata Property Path means?

Comment: Hi @Nandan Chaturvedi,                                                                                     I have given In Detail.view.xml                                                                       
                                                                                                                   
<Label text="{ path:'{Xdata}',formatter:'.formatLabel'}"/>                                   
In Controller formatLabel: function (oDataString) {} Debugger is hit formatLabel. But How to get that value. I was checking in DOM also but value is not coming. Can you guide?